# django users table - access from other application (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, django, authentication

I have a working django application with the auth_user table. I want to authenticate users in this table in another C# .NET (Web API) application.

What do I need to share to my C# application? I assume I need the SECRET_KEY, and to know how django creates the password hash.

Comment: You don't need the SECRET_KEY. That is not used for password hashing. You just need to implement the same hashing algorithm that you have configured Django to use.

Comment: Is it just the pdkdf2 hashing? doesn't it has some parameters that django uses?

Comment: I suggest you look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c651331b34b7c3841c126959e6e52879bc6f0834/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L232).